# Why is Publish is faster than Release in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a game in XNA, and I noticed that when I publish the game runs faster than when I run in release mode.  I have optimization enabled in the build options, trace and debug disabled.  What else could be going on here.  This is causing difficulty for tuning.   Has anyone seen this before?  What could be going on?

Comment: Can't help you because I never spend time with Publish Mode but could you give us an estimate of how faster your game is running ? Have you set the framerate to 60fps and does the RunningSlowly flag is enabled during Release Mode and not in Publish Mode ? What is the average time between two ticks in Release Mode and in Publish Mode ? (sorry to *answer* with questions...!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you run it in Release mode? Do you press F5 or the green arrow button ('Start Debugging')? If so, this will run your program with the VS debugger attached, in some cases slowing code down by more than an order of magnitude (seen such a difference with CPU intensive code using XNA). Either run your code with Ctrl+F5 ('Start Without Debugging') or from outside VS (the same thing, as far as I know).